# Selecting samples related to particular frequencies using Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am working on EEG dataset which is sampled at 1kHz. I have applied the band-pass filter from 4-40 Hz and extracted segments using sliding window of 2 seconds for FFT. Now I want to select 200 samples corresponding to 5-35 Hz. Would someone please guide me how to do that using Scipy or Numpy.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a bandpass filter of 5-35 Hz on the data you extracted. You can use the scipy.signal.filtfilt function (it avoids adding a phase to your signal):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html

You could feed this function with Butterworth filter coefficients (using your original sampling rate). You can use the scipy.signal.butter function for that.